# Extra dateSpecified parameter added to service method

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a method that looks like this

```
someFunction(string str, DateTime date);
```

When I want to call this method from my client I have to pass an extra parameter called dateSpecified.

Now I understand that this parameter is added for datatypes such as DateTime, int, etc. But I do not want it there, how can I get rid of it?

Comment: If the method signature in the client's code won't match the method signature in the server's code, than, apparently, your WCF service contract isn't in sync. You should regenerate the client binding.

Comment: The extra bool value dateSpecified is added automaticly when I deploy the service. Its to differentiate passed value from default value of optional parameters.

Comment: So then just pass in the correct value. What's your problem with that?

Comment: I meant extra bool parameter not value.
I write the service method like above, but when the service is deployed the method has 3 parameters namely String str, DateTime date, bool dateSpecified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful to see the service contract, but my best suggestion right now is to handle optional parameters manually if you don't like the way the Studio tools are handling them, e.g. use "DateTime? date" and if null is passed treat it as not provided.